# Explain the differences between worship and obeisance

Tags: word-choice

In English is there a substantive difference between the words obeisance and worship?

In biblical Greek the word translated worship can mean adoration toward deity or respectful bowing toward another person like a curtsy or ceremonial bow.

Yet in English we rarely if ever would use worship in the context of genuflection toward a fellow human. Instead we might use the word obeisance.

Are the words worship and obeisance interchangeable in English?  Explain why or why not.

Comment: Definitely not. You worship God (or, metaphorically, a person you are madly in love with), but you do obeisance to a high-ranking human being. Both words would be unnatural in the opposite context.

Comment: @KateBunting Based on that comment would it be poor translation from greek to English to use worship in a context of a person bowing before a high ranking official like a king?

Comment: Yes, it would; that is what I meant by 'unnatural in the opposite context'.

Comment: The differences are pretty clear in a straightforward dictionary search. If that does not clarify the matter, please return to us to say where the difficulty is.

Comment: Not really up on Brit-speak, but isn't "your worship" still a formal term for referring to someone with a "title" in the UK?

Comment: @HotLicks yes it is, although getting dated now.

Comment: Kris, dictionaries are handy tools for finding and checking the meanings of words. Here is a relevant link to a dictionary: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obeisance You could try finding the meaning of worship in such a dictionary.

Comment: Closing this question was dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not interchangeable. *Worship* has been increasingly associated with the divine over the past few hundred years, whereas *obeisance* remains associated with people. The Oxford English Dictionary in "[worship, n.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/230345)" lists the divine definition first, and then lists the one for people as rare:

> 8. a. Reverence or veneration paid to a being or power regarded as supernatural or divine; the action or practice of displaying this by appropriate acts, rites, or ceremonies.
>    [...]
> 9. Respect or honour shown to a person or thing; the action or practice of displaying this. Now *rare*.

It is hard to say *why* that shift happened. Worship (originally from *worth*+*ship*) as a quality was often applied to knights and other high class figures as well as divine ones in Middle English and Early Modern English. It could be that the connection between *worship* and *honor* weakened as value systems like chivalry became more decorative than functional, which is why the term is kept in the more restrictive sense of a title ([Your Worship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worship_(style))) but does not remain in active use. (Most people don't have to genuflect to their lord.) It could also be that the Reformation in England brought a new interest in lexically distinguishing between the respect paid to any person (including a priest) and God. It could be entirely incidental - writers used *worship* more in reference to the divine and people believed that *worship* pertained to divinity.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the definitions of [worship](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worship)

> to have or show a strong feeling of respect and admiration for God or a god:

and [obeisance](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obeisance)

> the fact of obeying or respecting someone, or something you do that expresses this

from the Cambridge online dictionary it is clear that **worship** is to do with someone's personal relationship to a deity whereas **obeisance** is to do with their commitment to another person with higher status and more power.

Although 'Worship' is often expressed through 'acts of worship' such as kneeling, crossing oneself, touching one's forehead to the floor in prayer, bowing before images of the gods and so on these acts are considered to be the external manifestations of the internal drive. There are often social pressures to do this but the most important thing is considered to be the internal response.

'Obeisance' on the other hand can be demanded either by the powerful person or by social convention and is usually expressed in physical action. Although the definition says that the it is "the fact of obeying or respecting someone" there is no suggestion that a person giving obeisance to another considers them to be anything other than a person of higher status. Obeisance, therefore, is more concerned with observable actions or audible words than worship. It is quite possible to "give obeisance" (that is perform the outer show) to someone without necessarily respecting or supporting them. You can only *appear* to worship a given deity.

'Worship' is also used to describe the reaction to a romantically loved one (as in "she was besotted with him and worshipped the ground he walked on") but this is, again, a personal internal emotion and the beloved does not, usually, demand 'obeisance' from the lover (unless the relationship is abusive in some way).